# Количество корней и вложеных элементов в treeview

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Можете написать код, который бы выдавал допустим:
если ветка имеет вид:

```
 1. Первый Элемент
   1. А
   2. Б
 2. Второй Элемент
  1. В
  2. Г
 3. Третий Элемент
  1. Д
```

то выдал бы сообщение:

```
Первый элемент - А,Б
Второй элемент - В,Г
Третий элемент - Д
```

Comment: Что за структура данных, мен ? =) Дерево, список, двумерный массив?

Comment: я же написал TreeView, если так не понятно то вот скрин http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120627/unTrThDL.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
function TForm1.Branch(Itm: TTreeNode): String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:=Itm.Text;
  for i:=0 to Itm.Count-1 do
    Result:=Result+' '+Branch(Itm.Item[i]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for i:=0 to TreeView1.Items.Count-1 do
    if TreeView1.Items[i].Parent=nil then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Branch(TreeView1.Items[i]));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Давно не пишу на Паскале, но должно быть примерно так

```
tn := tree.TopItem;
while tn <> nil do
  begin
    Writeln (tn + ' - ' + tn.ChildNodes);
    tn := tn.getNextSibling;
  end;
```

Comment: Не работает